# How do I cite an article not written in English?

Tags: citations

I am writing a research paper where references have to be addressed by author name and the year of his/her publication. I.e (Hamidi 2016).

The article that I am planning to include is in German language http://emarcon.de/social-media-im-krisen-und-katastrophenfall/, so what is the best way to cite this article in my manuscript?

Comment: Why would you think you would cite it any different than an English article?

Comment: @DSVA because I just only found the needed information in that article. Do that affect the quality of the paper if I cite something from a non-English article? maybe I have to post it as a separate question.

Comment: @Krebto i's completely fine if your source is in a different language, the language also doesn't tell you anything about the quality of the data/research/... and it certainly doesn't affect the quality of your paper to cite those.

Comment: Small piece of advice: If you use this article, really read it. I once encountered a problem where many people in my field used an article that was only available in Russian. Instead of reading said article, they believed other authors about what it said. This led to a "chinese whispers" kind of problem, that people attributed many nice results (even wrong ones) to said article, that (after sending it through google translate) turned out to not been covered at all by the original work.

Answer (score 1):

If an article contains the information you need, then you can cite it, regardless of the language it is written in. (The precise style of the citation will depend upon the publisher.) Many readers will be unable to verify the validity of your claim. To limit this shortcoming, you could provide a direct translation or summarise key points.